# How to move an object along a path in swiftui

Tags: animation, swiftui

I try to move an Image along a path in a vein. I didn't find how to do it. Here my present code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State  var chemin = Path {chemin in
            chemin.move(to: CGPoint(x: 620, y: 0))
            chemin.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:460, y:120))
            chemin.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 480, y: 200), control: CGPoint(x: 380, y: 220))
            chemin.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:590, y:120))
            chemin.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 680, y: 320), control: CGPoint(x: 890, y: 160))
            chemin.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 330))
            chemin.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 160))
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Image("carte").resizable().ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack{
            Image("corona").resizable().frame(width: 150, height: 100, alignment: .center).animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3), value: true)
             
        }
             chemin.stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 3).ignoresSafeArea()
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find the correct animation type

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions this might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, the apple tutorial doesn't show how to move an object along along a path. I ask myself if the animation I am looking for should be a modifier of the image or of the path itself. Thank you helping me out!

Comment: It isn’t as simple as finding the correct animation . If you search for your question on SO and google you will find different approaches. Give those a try, when you have a specific issue we can help. Right now your question is too broad, it is more like a code request/task vs an issue. There are other websites for that.

Comment: I searched plenty of sites and didn't resolve my issue... Could you please give me some keywords I should look after on SO or google? I searched for "moving an object along a path", "complex animations", "path animation", "environment object". As you imagine, I am new on SwiftUi. I thought my question required  a one-line-answer which could help me out, but as I understand it, it is much more complicated. So excuse me if you felt I treated you as "a code writing service". Thank you anyway!

Comment: If it is a one-line-answer, then you would already found it. Also, did you try checking the link which I attached for you here?

Answer (score 1):

```
I finally found how to do it, here's the code with some extra-functions:

    import SwiftUI



    struct FollowEffect: GeometryEffect {
        var pct: CGFloat = 0
        let path: Path
        var rotate = true

        var animatableData: CGFloat {
            get { return pct }
            set { pct = newValue }
        }

        func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {

            if !rotate {
                let pt = percentPoint(pct)

                return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: pt.x, y: pt.y))
            } else {
                // Calculate rotation angle, by calculating an imaginary line between two points
                // in the path: the current position (1) and a point very close behind in the path (2).
                let pt1 = percentPoint(pct)
                let pt2 = percentPoint(pct - 0.01)

                let a = pt2.x - pt1.x
                let b = pt2.y - pt1.y

                let angle = a < 0 ? atan(Double(b / a)) : atan(Double(b / a)) - Double.pi

                let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: pt1.x, y: pt1.y).rotated(by: CGFloat(angle))

                return ProjectionTransform(transform)
            }
        }
        func percentPoint(_ percent: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {

               let pct = percent > 1 ? 0 : (percent < 0 ? 1 : percent)

               let f = pct > 0.999 ? CGFloat(1-0.001) : pct
               let t = pct > 0.999 ? CGFloat(1) : pct + 0.001
               let tp = path.trimmedPath(from: f, to: t)

               return CGPoint(x: tp.boundingRect.midX, y: tp.boundingRect.midY)
           }
       }

    



    
    
    
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    
    
@State var chemin: Path = Path {path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 620, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:460, y:120))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 480, y: 200), control: CGPoint(x: 380, y: 220))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:590, y:120))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 680, y: 320), control: CGPoint(x: 890, y: 160))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 330))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 160))
    }
    @State private var flag = false
    

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Image("carte").resizable().ignoresSafeArea()
                        

                        // Animate movement of Image
                        Image("corona").resizable().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50).offset(x: -25, y: -25).modifier(FollowEffect(pct: self.flag ? 1 : 0, path: chemin)).onAppear {
                                                                                                        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 4.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                                                                                                                                   self.flag.toggle()
                                                                                                                                                 }
                                                                                                                                            }

                                                                                                                                            }.frame(alignment: .topLeading)
                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                            
     
                
            
        
        
       
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) If you select your code in Xcode and press `ctrl-i`, it'll format it for you. 2) Storing a `Path` that you never mutate inside a `@State` variable doesn't make sense -- you can (should) remove the `@State` property wrapper on it.